# htaccess just working one time

Tags: .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` with the following settings:

```
AuthName "veuillez vous authentifier"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/.pass"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

And a `.pass`:

```
pass:password
```

(These values are not the real)

It's working perfectly, but just the first time. And even after I delete all history in my browser when I want to return into one web page, I don't have any username and password required.

Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: You will need to restart browser to get auth dialog again.

Comment: @anubhava, it's working. Thank a lot I didn't thing to this solution! thank!